# Executing More than 3 Futures does not work

Tags: scala, sbt, future, scala-dispatch

I m using dispatch library in my sbt project. When I initialize three future and run them it is working perfectly But I increase one more future then it goes to a loop.

My code:

```
    //Initializing Futures
    def sequenceOfFutures() ={

     var pageNumber: Int = 1
        var list ={Seq(Future{})}

        for (pageNumber <- 1 to 4) {
          list ++= {
            Seq(
              Future { 
              str= getRequestFunction(pageNumber); 
              GlobalObjects.sleep(Random.nextInt(1500)); 

              }
              )
          }
        }
    Future.sequence(list)
    }
Await.result(sequenceOfFutures, Duration.Inf)
```

And then getRequestionFunction(pageNumber) code:

```
def getRequestionFunction(pageNumber)={

  val h=Http("scala.org", as_str)

while(h.isComplete){

   Thread,sleep(1500);
}

}
```

I tried based on one suggestion from [How to configure a fine tuned thread pool for futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285284/how-to-configure-a-fine-tuned-thread-pool-for-futures/15285441#15285441)

I added this to my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent._

implicit val ec = new ExecutionContext {
    val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);

    def execute(runnable: Runnable) {
        threadPool.submit(runnable)
    }

    def reportFailure(t: Throwable) {}
}// Still didn't work
```

So when I use more than four Futures then it keeps await forever. Is there some solution to fix it?

But it didn't work Could someone please suggest how to solve this issue?