# How to work with timer in cats effect without ExecutionContext.global and IOApp?

Tags: scala, spring-data-jpa, scala-cats

I have a simple sequence of IO operaion with 5 second pause.

```
  implicit val timer = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)

  def doSth(str: String): IO[Unit] = IO(println(str))
  def greeting(): IO[Unit] =
    doSth("Before timer.") *>
      Timer[IO].sleep(5 second) *>
      doSth("After timer")

  val a = greeting().unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()
```

How to make timer without `ExecutionContext.global`, `IOApp` or to fix amount of threads in `ExecutionContext.global`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
implicit val timer = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)))
```

[How to configure a fine tuned thread pool for futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285284/how-to-configure-a-fine-tuned-thread-pool-for-futures)